# Can I check if event happened during an hour, regardless of date? Moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I'm tracking the usage of a device, and showing users their usage trends by hour.  Basically, I need to look through `times` documents and see if the device was "on" betwen 6pm and 7pm, then 7pm and 8pm, the 8pm and 9pm, and so on for all 24 hours.

This is what I originally wrote:

```
      // loop through 24 hours of the day
      for (let j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
        const beginningOfHour = moment().startOf('day').add(j, 'hour').toDate()
        const endOfHour = moment(beginningOfHour).add({ m: 59, s: 59, ms: 999 }).toDate()

        const cumulativeHours = timePerPeriod(beginningOfHour, endOfHour, myTimes)  // calculation func

        trendsArray.push(cumulativeHours)
      }
```

This doesn't work becasue `beginningOfHour` and `endOfHour` also have a date attached to them.

I can't figure out how to check my `times` documents for just the hour portion, without any reference to date.  Any advice on how to do this?

EDIT:
Here is what a `times` document looks like:

```
_id: 5e56cf9ae65bf2b30a6ab525  // ObjectID type
user_id: 5e56bb2b40ad526200401773  // ObjectID type
start: 2020-02-27T00:00:00.000+00:00  // Date type
stop: 2020-02-27T06:00:00.000+00:00  // Date type
```

The device can be on for any length of time, like 3 months straight or 15 seconds.  Each `time` document is examined, and if it is on for any length of time during that hour duration, the length in miliseconds that it was on during that hour period is returned by my calculation function (called `cumulativeHours` above).

Comment: Can the data contain events ranging for more than a day? If so, are they cumulative? _e.g. If every day for the past week I've turned on my device at 8:30pm, should it return 7?_ Also, can you provide example data which it provided in the `myTimes` variables?

Comment: I edited my question with more info.

Comment: Could you convert the 24-hour times to integers called `time` and use `time > start && time < end`?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the times and filter by the hour of day and/or minute of the timestamp by using the `.hour()` or the `.minute()` methods on the moment objects like this ( for simplicity reasons i only check the hour):

```js
let sampleArrayOfDateTimes = [
  moment("2013-02-08 08:59"),
  moment("2013-02-08 09:00"),
  moment("2013-02-08 09:30"),
  moment("2013-02-08 10:00")
]

// find datetimes between 09:00 (including) and 10:00 (excluding)

let arrayWithTimesBetween9and10 = sampleArrayOfDateTimes.filter(datetime => datetime.hour() == 9);

console.log("the following datetimes are between 09:00 and 09:59");
arrayWithTimesBetween9and10.forEach(datetime => {
  console.log(datetime.format());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but he added details to the question. That's not actually what he wants to do

Answer (score 0):

As the question was edited and is now asking for time ranges overlapping each other here comes a solution for the edited version. This is a very simplified approach, which doesn't take into account minutes or timespans over multiple days, but it hope it conveys the idea. Basically for every timespan-combination all 4 possibilites need to be checked (timespans overlap fully, do not overlap at all or only start or only end time is in between):

```js
let sampleDatetimeRanges = [
  {
    start: moment("2013-02-08 09:00"),
    end: moment("2013-02-08 10:00")
  },
  {
    start: moment("2013-02-08 08:00"),
    end: moment("2013-02-08 12:00")
  },
  {
    start: moment("2013-02-08 13:00"),
    end: moment("2013-02-08 18:00")
  } 
];

function isBetweenHours(start, end, hourInQuestion) {
  return start <= hourInQuestion && end >= hourInQuestion;
}


// calculate the timespan between 09:00 and 10:00
const rangeStart = 9;
const rangeEnd = 11;
const hoursCount = sampleDatetimeRanges.map(current => {
  let startHour = current.start.hour();
  let endHour = current.end.hour();
  if (startHour <= rangeStart && endHour >= rangeEnd) { // full time covered
    return rangeEnd - rangeStart;
  } else if (startHour <= rangeStart && isBetweenHours(rangeStart, rangeEnd, endHour)) { // only end time in timespan
    return endHour - rangeStart;
  } else if (isBetweenHours(rangeStart, rangeEnd, startHour) && endHour >= rangeEnd) { // only start time in timespan
    return rangeEnd - startHour;
  } else if (isBetweenHours(rangeStart, rangeEnd, startHour) && isBetweenHours(rangeStart, rangeEnd, endHour)) {
    return endHour - startHour;
  }
  // not in timespan
  return 0;

}).reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0)

console.log(`hours covered in the timespan from ${rangeStart} to ${rangeEnd}: ${hoursCount}. `);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: ```let startHour = current.start.hour();```  This line you have is more or less what I need, but .hour() is not a valid method for javascript Date objects.  and the getTime() method returns the unix timestamp, which is not what I need either.

Comment: @Brian Why not convert/parse it to momentjs-objects like i did? You've added momentjs as tag to your question.